# Realm doesn't always return an object for its primary key from the cloud, although it does exist there

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am quite new to Realm and now I'm facing the issue, mentioned in the title. Basically, one of my `Realms` is a `User` class (**this is different from `Users` that is created when new users log in**) in `Realm Cloud`. The class has a `userId` property, which is set as its primary key. Now, I try to fetch users for a particular primary key with the following line:

```
let user = realm?.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: "f677ca48b17bc7b90a886dd5d50148c1")
```

I do see that there is a user in the cloud with this primary key, but he is not always returned. I mean, say, if I run the same code 10 times, I will get the user only 4 times out of 10 (roughly). The above code is run from a method, which is always called when the controller is on screen. Also, there is no condition checking in the method for that part of code, so it is always called when the method is called.

I've also checked the `realm` property and it is not `nil`, so I don't quite understand why this happens.

The same happens when I try to get the current user by the line:

```
currentUser = realm?.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: SyncUser.current?.identity)
```

The `identity` value is not nil (I print it before calling the code).

**UPDATED**

Here is how the `User` looks like:

```
 class User: Object {

 @objc dynamic var userId: String = ""
 @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

 override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
     return "userId"
   }
}
```

Maybe, I am missing something or that is a problem/bug on the cloud side, I don't know. If you've encountered such an issue and/or know what could cause it, I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your `User.self` Object

Answer (score 0):

This is caused because of the race condition that could pops up when you try to access a reference that is not on the main thread & being worked on by other thread .

therefore it will return nil each most of the time when you try to call it from the main thread because `Realm` had no chance to write or read from yet as you are accessing it directly .

**What to do:**

Make sure that your properties in the `User` object are marked with `dynamic` .

> properties of your Object subclasses need to be declared with the `dynamic` modifier to allow `Realm` to override the getter and setter of the property.
>
> Without this the Swift compiler will access the object's instance
>   variable directly, which doesn't provide any opportunity for Realm to
>   read or write data from the Realm file.

Also please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518028/8192960) answer .

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question, so check it, please. Also, as far as I understood from your answer, this happens because there is a race condition because the `realm` could be not on the main thread, so sometimes it doesn't manage to access it at the right time. Am I right, or missing something?

Comment: I've also tried to follow the suggestion in the question you've linked, but unfortunately I get the same result: a random appearance of users during iterations.

Comment: let realm = try! Realm()
let specificPerson = realm.object 
can u try accessing it like this

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately it turns out I can't because I'm using query-based sync and for that I need to configure the Realm with synched user's configurations.